# C++: passing address of int as parameter

Tags: c++, pointers, parameters, reference, memory-address

Why is "Void" actually returning "6" ?

```
void Void (int &ref){
    ref++;
}

int main () {

    int test= 5;
    Void(test);
    cout << test;  // is 6      

    return 0;
}
```

I don't quite understand what's happening here. With Void(test) I'm not passing test's address. 
Why not "Void(&test);"?
Why is ref++ adding 1 to the value 5? Shouldn't it be "*ref++"?

Comment: When you use & writing "ref" means "*ref"

Comment: @DGomez No, it doesn't. `Type &ident` means a reference, `Type *ident` means a pointer.

Comment: I mean, has the same "effect", sure is not the same

Comment: Why do I need pointers then? Only for storing addresses?

Comment: Read about Dynamic Data Structures, if you wanna know some good stuff with pointers.

Comment: Do you know any online sources for that?

Comment: http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/103/LinkedListBasics.pdf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int &ref = test;
```

`ref` is initialized as a reference to the variable `test`. A reference is essentially an alias to another object. Despite the familiar syntax (namely the amersand *`&`*) this is **not** taking the address of anything and, semantically, has *nothing* to do with pointers.

Answer (score 4):

```
void Void (int &ref)
               ^
             this!
```

You're [passing it by reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_%28C%2B%2B%29).

Answer (score 2):

The parameter of `Void` has type `int&`. The `&` in `int&` is part of the type. It makes it a reference type. It has nothing to do with the `&` you might use to get the address of an object.

As the parameter type is a reference type, any object passed to it is *passed by reference*. This means the `ref` inside the function refers to the `test` object outside of it. Therefore, `ref++` has an effect on `test`.

This is as opposed to when you do not have a `&` in the type and it is *passed by value*. This would copy the object into the function and `ref++` would only affect the copy.

Answer (score 1):

```
void Void (int &ref){
   ref++;
}
```

You passed parameter by `reference`, so any change on the parameter `ref` inside `Void` will directly apply on the calling variable, i.e., `test` in this case since `ref` is a reference to `test`

Answer (score 0):

You're passing it by reference. When you pass a variable by reference in C++, you don't need to have & before the argument. If the parameter of a function is a reference, than you pass the arguments by reference at function call.